# Custom directive not working in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a custom directive for date picker in angular js but that seems to be not working .  (angular-resource.js is included)

**code :**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[
    'ngRoute',
    'myAppControllers',
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'ngSanitize',
]);

myApp.directive('jqdatepicker', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
         link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
            element.datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'DD, d  MM, yy',
                onSelect: function (date) {
                    scope.date = date;
                    scope.$apply();
                }
            });
        }
    };
});


<input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" ng-model="formData[field.name.field_name]" jqdatepicker/>
```

[There](http://jsfiddle.net/kevinj/TAeNF/2/) is a fiddle which is working but my code doesn't

Comment: What's "not working" about it? Did you put a breakpoint inside the `link`? Any errors in console?

Comment: @RGraham when I click inside input type , datepicker must displayed but its not showing and no error in console .

Comment: Your fiddle works? So have you included jQuery & jQuery UI in your angular app?

Comment: @RGraham yes , they are their . one more thing my input type is added after I select some options . or you can say I am appending html as we did in jquery . may be thats why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You forgot ng-app directive to tell the page,what module must work on that template.

Comment: I have added ng-app in document's body

Comment: but what is the problem? the link example you gave,is working fine how I see

Comment: Then may be there are some jquery conflicts which preventing datepicker to be render on template